# Visual Studio can't find any of the CRT files (like assert.h)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, crt

I think I've wrongly deleted some files, because Windows can't find assert.h --- I don't know what to do. I've reinstalled Visual Studio 2017 Community and I've installed CRT, but now the file is called cassert. I'm using some highly sensitive tempelates and I can't afford that. I tried installing CRT for Windows, but it didn't work for Windows 10. So what's wrong here?

I don't get any errors, I don't need to test it, because I know it's erroneous. There's a red squigly line under #include

Thanks.

Comment: What are 'highly sensitive templates' and why can't you afford them?

Comment: Did you check that your solution is using the SDK you have installed?

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't need a separate CRT, so if you want to use a specific one you probably just need to tell VS where to find it.

Comment: The CRT was split in two a while ago, assert.h belongs to the "universal C runtime" subset.  A typical install location is C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt.  If you randomly deleted files then reinstalling from scratch is highly recommended.